# Cassandra multiple data center

Tags: cassandra, storage, consistency

I have three datacenter named A,B and C. They are almost of same size. At some point of time A and C has 20 GB of available space but B has left with 10 GB. If we want to insert data more than 10 GB How this will work, Where data will go?

Answer (score 1):

Where the data go depends on the replication settings of your keyspaces.  If keyspace is configured to replicate to three data centers (a, b, c), then data will go to all of them. If it's configured to replicate only to a & b, then it will go to both of them.